# SSIS Date Format Convert

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

I created variable with datatype datetime in ssis.

by default it come with `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format.

How can I convert a date from `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format to `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` format in `datetime` variable.

Ex: 
Variable is: `05/12/2018 18:14:03`
Output should be
`05-12-2018 18:14:03`

Answer (score 2):

You don't convert the formats of `datetime` variables.  You can only give it a format when converting it to a string.

Comment: I did lot of design(dev server) in ssis based on dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss. But in production default variable datetime format is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. Now i need to change in variable level only.

Comment: Probably the two servers have different locale settings.   Check there.

Comment: yes. It is different, I need to handle it. Any suggesion

Comment: Make them the same.

Comment: It is not possible as others will affect

Comment: need to handle it in variable level

Comment: Well then you're stuck.   There is no way to change the format of a datetime at the variable level.  It's not possible.

Comment: Do you meant we can't change date format in ssis variable(datetime datatype)?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Under no circumstances should it matter what format a `DATE/DATETIME` datatype is. that is a display layer issue. When you are inserting this into a database it will go in as a `DATETIME`. You only change the format once you are displaying the data. As far as SSIS and any RDBMS is concerned it's just a datetime and the formatting is 100% irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I beleive from the comments of the other answer you may have a misunderstanding of what's happening here.

In both SQLServer and SSIS `DATETIME` is just simply a data type and is stored as such. Now when you are querying those columns from your table in the database on two different servers that have different settings for how they should display that data you'll get `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` depending on your region settings. However this **DOES NOT** mean that SQL Server or SSIS is storing those values in that format. It's just defaulted to display that way.

Now if you need to change how that column is **DIPSLAYED** when you query the table you can see a list of conversions that may help you on this [ugly looking website](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/).